# Vue: Conditions are getting trimmed

Tags: vue.js

in my component, I have the following condition:

```
if (this.getAppSetupColorTint == '#FFFFFF' || this.getAppSetupColorBackground == '#FFFFFF' || (this.getAppSetupColorBackground == '#000000' && this.getAppSetupColorBackground == '#000000') ) {


}
```

but when I throw in a `debugger` statement, the JS in the console shows the inner paranthesis stripped out like this:

```
if (this.getAppSetupColorTint == '#FFFFFF' || this.getAppSetupColorBackground == '#FFFFFF' || this.getAppSetupColorBackground == '#000000' && this.getAppSetupColorBackground == '#000000') {

}
```

Comment: Could you please be more clear about the issue?

Comment: the inner condition is `(this.getAppSetupColorBackground == '#000000' && this.getAppSetupColorBackground == '#000000')`  Stripping away the paranthesis changes that and I can't tell why they are getting stripped

Comment: Why you are comparing same things in &&, that is a wrong binary logic javascript is just simplifying it before rendering.

Comment: Those conditions are too long. I recommend you to make a function which returns true or false for each if statement.

Comment: Agree with @Grampet. You need to refactor these and also try to use === as you are comparing a hex string

Comment: In this case, the conditions are evalulated the same way (left to right) with or without the parentheses. Why are you concerned that the parentheses are stripped away?